# Align nested items in separate frames in beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize

I am working in beamer. I have used some `itemize` list in one slide, and I want to continue the indent of the nested list in the first slide to the next slide. Note that I do not want to use `allowframebreaks`. How can I achieve this? The situation is shown in the figure below.

[image]

[image]

From the figure, understand that I need to align "nested thing 2" with "blah" in the itemize environment.
MWE:

```
\begin{frame}{First frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item something
    \item some other thing
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[$\hookrightarrow$] nested thing
        \item[$\hookrightarrow$] nested thing 2
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Second frame}
\begin{itemize}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[$\hookrightarrow$] blah 
    \item[$\hookrightarrow$] blah blah
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

However, I get an error along with the output "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item". Is there any workaround, such as using `\setlength`, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an empty dummy `\item` to the top level list:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{First frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item something
    \item some other thing
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[$\hookrightarrow$] nested thing
        \item[$\hookrightarrow$] nested thing 2
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Second frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item[]
\begin{itemize}
    \item[$\hookrightarrow$] blah 
    \item[$\hookrightarrow$] blah blah
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @AbhinavSinha You're welcome!